# Why doesn't this function exit after the first iteration?

Tags: javascript, function, return, palindrome

I do understand how the following function works in general. BUT why doesn't it exit after the first iteration (when there is a palindrome)? It checks the first character against the last in the if statement, which is true, what should (in my logic) execute the return statement... Thank you for any help explaining this! :)

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < lowerCaseStr.length; i++)
  debugger;
    if (lowerCaseStr[i] === lowerCaseStr[lowerCaseStr.length - i - 1]){
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: btw, you iterate only `debugger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch the logic, check for inequality and return `false`. If you reach the end, return `true`.

```
function palindrome(str) {
    var lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
    for (var i = 0; i < lowerCaseStr.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        if (lowerCaseStr[i] !== lowerCaseStr[lowerCaseStr.length - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: 1. Why is this any different than my way? and 2. Back to my question: why doesnt the function (loop) stop after comparing the first two characters? THANK YOU!

Comment: it is different for checking not for equalness but for not equal and the return value is switched as well, `true`becomes `false` and vice versa. you exit with the first found same character, but you need not to check sameness, but the inequality.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't exit after the first iteration but after `lowerCaseStr.length` iterations because your code is equivalent to the code below

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 0; i < lowerCaseStr.length; i++){ 
      debugger;
  }

  if (lowerCaseStr[lowerCaseStr.length] === lowerCaseStr[-1]){
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

that is, it iterates `lowerCaseStr.length;` times but the only thing it does for each iterates is call `debugger` after that it tests to elements in the array that doesn't exists. (Both indices are out of bounds). That results in a comparison of two times `undefined` `undefined === undefined` which is always true.

As a side node if you return either true or false depending on a boolean expression then consider using one return statement instead:

```
return (lowerCaseStr[i] === lowerCaseStr[lowerCaseStr.length - i - 1]);
```